# After setting "type" field to module, import error still persist

Tags: node.js

After reading how I can use import statement in node docs and configure it in the package.json, the import error still persist. My requirement is that I don't want to use the `require` statement.
Is it something that I'm not seeing???

[Error output on console.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Si7JI.png)

`Package.json`

```
{
  "name": "memory-server",
  "type": "module",
  ...
  ...
}
```

`Exported Class`

```
export default class testDBHelper{
    *Blah Blah Blah*
}
```

`Imported Class`

```
import TestDbHelper from "../testUtils/testDBHelper";
```

Comment: Does [this](https://itsmycode.com/solved-uncaught-syntaxerror-cannot-use-import-statement-outside-a-module/#:~:text=The%20Uncaught%20syntaxerror%3A%20cannot%20use,file%20from%20the%20dist%20folder.) helps?

Comment: It didn't help @ApoorvaChikara, As you can see, I'm exporting a default class.